# MYSQL better way to create category tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying create a schema for profile management system.

Since each profile will belong to different category for example  sports,political ,non profit organization etc.
Each profile contain different info or details from one another so

1.My question is it better to create all columns in single table or creating different tables for each category because if i create in single category it will be large columns in mysql when category will increases or each category may come some related tables ?

```
users
id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | dob | primary_email | secondary_email | password | primary_phone | secondary_phone | home_address |  

profile_categories

id | category_name | 



user_categories

id | user_id | category_id 


political 
id | category_id | political_person_name | .....
```

Comment: I guess you can use [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model for categories meta data

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid,thanks for the response.can you describe some example if possible.thanks again

Comment: Why tag a MySQL question with PostgreSQL and SQLite?

Comment: @muistooshort.since its a table design related question so i added .

Comment: what is `profile_categories` and what is this `user_categories.category_id` What I mean is there is not enough information about your data or needs to come up with a data model.  How are these things related.

Comment: Prefer creating separate tables. Read about Normalization.
 if user has multiple categories it wont replicate the same record in main table.
also if you want to keep adding new types , you just have to create another table which maps to original table with a relationship

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix.user_categories table usede when user bleong to multiple category. for example a user may be politcal leader as well as he may run non profit organization

Comment: @BRjava.thanks for the answer

Comment: Shouldn't the table `political` contain a `user_id`? And then the table `user_categories` would become obsolete.

Comment: Read a textbook on information modeling & database design.